# ssh specify default directory to check

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

Instead of `ssh "~/.ssh/somekey.pem" ubuntu@somehost`, is there a way to make ssh auto check the `~/.ssh` directory for keys so that I can simply do `ssh "somekey.pem" ubuntu@somehost` (i.e. omitting `~/.ssh`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the same host then try updating your `~/.ssh/config` file with the host info

```
Host dev
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github.key
  HostName dev.example.com
  Port 22000
  User fooey
```

then just type `ssh dev` to ssh in!